# How to convert a string into an NSDate?

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

Let's say I have something like `30-10-2025 12:53`, how could I convert that to an NSDate? I guess there's some class that takes this plus an format string that tells it how the date looks as a string, so it can parse it... where must I look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use NSDateFormatter

```
 NSDateFormatter *k= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [k setFormat:@"your string format"] //ex @"MM/DD/yyyy hh:mm:ss" 
 NSDate *d=[k dateFromString:yourString];
 [k release]
```

Here is a reference [DateFormatter ref](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateFromString:)

Comment: Mac OS X 10.5 and later, and all versions of iOS, expect format strings according to this specification: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NSDateFormatter class for this purpose.